# offset().left, offsetLeft, offset.left, what's the difference? why not use the pure js offsetLeft instead of the jQuery way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

Normally when getting the offset using jQuery I do `offset().left`. My understanding is that `offsetLeft` is pure javascript, so why not use this over the jQuery `offset().left`? Does it really help anything cross-browser? or?

And when using `offset().left` i've seen people take out the `()` so it's just `offset.left`, is this okay to do? Is it only okay to do if there's nothing in the parenthesis?

As a side note: I've heard that in IE7 when using the jQuery way of `offset().top` it gives a screwey offset based on how much you've scrolled. Someone in the comments on the  [jQuery API page for offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) said `document.getElementById(anchor).offsetTop` fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting offsets can be a little tricky in some browsers. `offsetTop` and `-Left` are incorrect in IE 6 and below and others like `offsetX` and `offsetY` are completely inconsistent across browsers (see [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html))

Generally, when a library includes some functionality even when the same functionality *seems* to already exist, it's usually done for cross-browser purposes.

As far as I can tell, using `offset.left` instead of `offset().left` shouldn't even work. The latter would be "get the `left` property of the object *returned by* the `offset()` function", which is what you'd want. The former, with no parentheses, would be "get the `left` property *of the function* `offset`", which doesn't make much sense to me (unless the object whose `offset` property you're accessing isn't a jQuery wrapper, in which case the `offset` property might not be a function, but instead an object with `left` and `top` properties).

But I'm not a jQuery expert